# How I can read a file in my Application folder?

Tags: c#, windows, service, stream, automation

Hi! I want to develop a windows service which I would install on a webserver. First I have to test my functions in a console application. I want to read a file in a Stream. In my Project Explorer I create a Folder with the name App_Data. In this I have three txt files and a pdf file.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"~/App_Data/PDFContent_de.txt",System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    string message = reader.ReadToEnd();

   //...
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have described the situation well, but then seem to have forgotten to ask a question :)

Comment: oh yes i get a error with my path ....I want to App_Data/... but I goes to bin/debug/App_Data/..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder you create is inside bin/debug

You can use "../../" to go back directories like

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"../../App_Data/PDFContent_de.txt",System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

or set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the file to "Copy if newer" and just use

```
string path=@"App_Data/PDFContent_de.txt"
```

or

```
string path=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"/App_Data/PDFContent_de.txt";
```

or

```
string path=Path.GetFullPath("App_Data/PDFContent_de.txt");
```